# Zoom in in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, zooming

Is there any option to zoom in or out in visual studio '05. Upgrading to '10 isn't an option here. I miss being able to look close up when I need it.

From what I can tell there is no native support, are there any ways to trick it into zooming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 is the first release which supports zooming on a file.  Prior to 2010 there is no zoom like capability.  In order to make the text bigger you'll need to bump up the fon size.

- Tools -> Options
- Evironment -> Fonts and Colors
- Change the Size parameter

Answer (score 0):

Zoom in the code? Holding ctrl + mouse scroll maybe resolve?

Comment: Thats only an option in visual studio 2010 as far as I can tell